# Problems with vertical margins in CSS

Tags: css, margins

In [this page](http://www.zorl.net/t20131005/) I'm trying to vertically center the text "Details..." with "XYZ" using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, but to no avail. I also want to decrease the space between title and table.

[image]

Strange thing: when I put the red border around the title to see what I did wrong, the centered text dropped below the left and right floats (see bottom image). I just added a `border`,  *nothing else was changed*.

Can someone please have a look at my code and suggest how to vertically align the title, and decrease the space below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> give float to your div. without float property these  all problems are occurring.

```
.class{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Check this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/9aAmt/)